# JavaScript game; bullets in array; when I shoot, ALL bullets in array refire from wherever the player is

Tags: javascript

There's a fiddle of the whole thing here - http://jsfiddle.net/Ey2eK/1/

But I think the problem parts are these functions. This one loads at the end of my main game loop:

```
 playerBullets.forEach(function() {
            if (this.x > WIDTH || this.x < 0 || this.y > HEIGHT || this.y < 0) { this.active = false;}
            playerBullets = playerBullets.filter(function(bullet) {
            return this.active;});

            bulletUpdate(this);
            bulletDraw(this);
          });
```

OK, so what I'm trying to do here is cycle through the playerBullets array, for each bullet, first I check if it's out of bounds and delete the bullet if it is, then I load bulletUpdate to update the bullets position, which is this formula:

```
bulletUpdate = function() {
    this.x += this.xVelocity;
    this.y += this.yVelocity;
  };
```

What I'm intending here is that for each bullet in the array, it's x and y positions are increased by it's velocity variables.

Then after I've calculated the new position of the bullet, I draw it with bulletDraw:

```
bulletDraw = function() {
    c.beginPath();
    c.save();
    c.translate(this.x,this.y);
    if (deltaX < 0) {
    c.rotate(this.angle);
    }
    else {
    c.rotate(this.angle);
    c.scale(-1,1);
    }
    c.translate(-this.x,-this.y);
    c.fillStyle = "#000000";
    c.rect(this.x, this.y, 2, 2);
    c.fill();
    c.restore();
    c.closePath();
  };
```

Basically drawing a little dot at the new this.x and this.y.

However, what actually seems to happen is that every time I click, bullets are redrawn from wherever the player is now. It's hard to explain but check out the Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Ey2eK/1/  and click a few times in the game area, you'll see (don't worry about the bullets only going in one direction, I'll work on that later).

What I want is for the bullets to carry on their journey as normal bullets should, so that eventually I can kill zombies with them.

Thanks for any help you might offer! I'm seriously stuck with this one.

Comment: Is it the bullet velocity that is being thrown off? What is the intended functionality?

Comment: The intended functionality of bulletDraw will be, to calculate the angle between the player and the mouse when it is clicked, and move the bullet to that location at a speed determined by xVelocity and yVelocity. However I couldn't figure out the maths for that (I'll have another go at that later), so I just gave xVelocity and yVelocity static values to see if the bullets worked otherwise. But they don't, they get redrawn with every click.

Comment: This should really go on code review. The heart of the issue is that you are using `this` in the wrong context and because of that you are getting inconsistent results. Cool approach overall though.

Comment: You know you can't really create objects in js right? "playerBullets.push(Bullet());" Bullet is not an object. If you're trying to create an instance of Bullet, you've got the wrong language.

Comment: @Nikki - That is not entirely accurate.

Comment: @TravisJ I'm know. But just from glancing at the code, it looks like he's trying to create objects.

Comment: everything in JS is an Object()

Comment: @Nikki yes that's right I'm trying to create a new "Bullet" object every click. edit: and push it into the playerBullets array.

Comment: @FlyingLizard maybe a more primitive approach would work. One array for x coords, one for y coords, and one for the image itself (in this case a shape)

Comment: @Nikki Do you mean to turn the bullets array into an array of arrays, rather than an array of objects? Or to have three separate arrays and push a value into each one on every click?

Comment: @FlyingLizard Parallel arrays. It's not a particularly clean method but I've made games in js before and it works. If you want a proper object orientated approach, try Java. I moved from js to Java for that very reason.

Comment: @Nikki Thanks for the suggestion! So is it not possible to push an object into an array in js? The parallel arrays idea might work for this one bullet type, and I'll try it, but it's going to get messy when there's multiple weapons, multiple bad guys, multiple types of bad guys. Objects would be ideal.

Comment: @FlyingLizard Technically in js, Arrays become objects if they themselves contain different data types. eg: var unitInfo=["aString",'aChar',anInt,anImage]; unitInfo is now an object. If you declare some jagged arrays like this, you'd have a collection of objects.....technically. It's not ideal and it's nothing like dealing with an OO language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ey2eK/4/)

The main issue is that you are not instantiating a new `Bullet` object on click. You're just redefining the values of Bullet function over and over.

`createBullet()` should look more like:

```
function createBullet() {
  var bullet = new Bullet();
  playerBullets.push(bullet);
}
```

But since you will have many instances of each bullet, you can actually replace the draw/update functions with bulletDraw/bulletUpdate, and invoke those inside the forEach call.

```
function Bullet() {
    ....
    this.bulletUpdate = function() { ... }
    this.bulletDraw = function() { ... }
}

// bullet refers to the current bullet that you're iterating over.
playerBullets.forEach(function(bullet) {
    if (bullet.x > WIDTH || bullet.x < 0 || bullet.y > HEIGHT || bullet.y < 0) { 
        bullet.active = false;
    }
    playerBullets = playerBullets.filter(function(bullet) {
        return bullet.active;
    });

    bullet.bulletUpdate();
    bullet.bulletDraw();
});
```